How to "borrow" an instance property type in Python type annotations?
In Python type annotations, is there some way to declare that a property has the same type as a property of another class? To "borrow" or copy the type from the other class?
For example, in this code, how could you say that bar should have the same type as the foo property of a Foo class instance?
# Python
from some_library import Foo  # class Foo

class Bar(Foo):
    bar: ??? typeof Foo.foo ???  # what goes here?

I'm looking for the equivalent of this TypeScript:
// TypeScript
import { Foo } from "some_library"; // class Foo

class Bar extends Foo {
  bar: Foo["foo"]; // bar has same type as `new Foo().foo`
}


More info: Foo is defined in type stubs that are not under my control. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve modifying third-party code or importing its private underscore types.
# some_library.pyi

from typing import TypedDict

class _FooErrorTypeDef(TypedDict, total=False):
    message: str
    severity: str    

class _FooPropTypeDef(TypedDict, total=False):
    status: str
    code: str | number
    errors: list[_FooErrorTypeDef] | None

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: _FooPropTypeDef


Type hints in Python are for static checkers, and instances imply dynamic types, which may be addressed using TypeVars.  Unless the Foo has some kind of TypeVar which may be shared and bounded between Foo and Bar, I am not sure how you can go about this.  Basically, you will need to tell us roughly how Foo is defined as a type, and how does it expose the type signature of Foo.foo.  Without this answer what you are asking for is impossible.

Take a look at this thread and see how Foo might need to be defined.

@metatoaster added the type stubs for Foo to the question, but they're third-party code so I won't be able to alter them. TypeScript makes it really easy to borrow property types like this; wondering if there's a Python equivalent.

You can't express "type of an attribute". The easiest solution would be to import _FooPropTypeDef (in if TYPE_CHECKING block if it's stub-only).

@STerliakov thanks, yeah, that's what I've been doing. Was hoping there was a way to avoid importing what's clearly meant to be a private type.

Yeah, you cannot avoid importing _FooPropTypeDef in Python for type checking in this particular instance because the property was defined with a concrete type.

You could suggest to upstream that the declaration should be "public". They probably should be, at least if the associated attributes are public.
